# javascript countdown just a little timer not working

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>timer</title>
        <script>
        function timer(button){
            var btn = document.getElementById("button1").value;
            var status;
                if(btn == "Start"){
                    button.value = "Stop";
                    status = true;
                };
                if(btn == "Stop"){
                    button.value = "Start";
                    status = false;
                    };
            var time = document.getElementById("numberinput").value;

            time = ++time;
            decrement();
            function decrement(){
                if(time > 0 && btn == "Start" && status == true){
                    time = --time;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = time;
                    var to = setTimeout(decrement, 1000);
                };
            };
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="info">Enter the number of secounds</div>
        <form id="form1">
            <input type="number" id="numberinput"><br />
            <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="timer(this)" value="Start">
            <div id="result"></div>
        </form>
</center>
</body>
```

Why do this code does this code not work?

It should be a time that counts down.

The start button works right but the stop doesn't.

I would be really helpful if someone could explain to me why this isn't working and give me an example on how to solve this.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but had some general coding practices wrong.

- `time = --time;` can be written as `time--;` (same for ++)
- I would personally not declare functions inside of functions (`decrement()`)
- Send values as parameters to other functions
- `setTimeout()` needs to have its first parameter as an anonymous function (little weird, but needs to happen)

Here is your working code:

```
window.timer = function(button){
    var btn = document.getElementById("button1").value;
    var status;
    if(btn == "Start"){
        button.value = "Stop";
        status = true;
    };
    if(btn == "Stop"){
        button.value = "Start";
        status = false;
    };
    var time = document.getElementById("numberinput").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = time;
    decrement(time, status);
};

window.decrement = function(time, status){
    var btn = document.getElementById("button1").value;
    if(time > 0 && btn == "Stop" && status == true){
        time--;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = time;
        var to = setTimeout(function() {
            decrement(time, status);
        },1000);
     };
 };
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fmn4src/

Comment: `setTimeout() needs to have its first parameter as an anonymous function` not exactly.  It needs to be a `function reference` which *can* be anonymous function, or it be a reference to a regular named function.

Comment: The regular named function has never worked for me. There are plenty of SO questions that show that strategy. But yes. Not required

Comment: Would it be possible if you press stop, that the time will simply stop and not reset, and that you could continue from the point where you have stopped the time? thanks!

Comment: Yes, change the value of the input box when you press "Stop" to reflect the current time.

Comment: if(btn == "Stop"){
        button.value = "Start";
        status = false;document.getElementById("numberinput").value = time;
    }; this doesn't work so how do i have to make it?